# field with key 'id' always comes zero spring boot mongodb repositories

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb spring boot starter and mongorepositories.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Repository :

```
public interface DeviceRepo extends MongoRepository<Device, String>{
    public List<Device> findByImei(String imei);

}
```

I am getting **value** properly but **id** always comes 0(zero) like below.

```
[{"id":0,"value":9},{"id":0,"value":6},{"id":0,"value":254}]
```

I have verified that id has non-zero values in mongodb database like below.

```
[ { "value" : 9, "id" : 181 }, { "value" : 6, "id" : 182 }, { "value" : 254, "id" : 66 }, { "value" : 0, "id" : 24 }, { "value" : 79, "id" : 67 }, { "value" : 7, "id" : 68 } ]
```

**NOTE : the 'id' is not objectId of mongodb. it is one of the other fields in entity which is normal.**

Please help.

Comment: Can you add the Device pojo to the post ?

Comment: Hi @Veeram i did not post the Device pojo because it has around 8 inner class objects in it...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the field name from 'id' to some other name like 'pid' and it worked.

So i suspect that mongodb repository was excluding the 'id' field.